# Python - Cancel timer thread

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a method which runs on a timer in the background of my main script:

```
def hello_world(self):
        print 'Hello!'
        threading.Timer(2,hello_world).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        hello_world()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '\nGoodbye!'
```

I am getting this  message when I attempt to keyboard interrupt my script:

```
Exception KeyboardInterrupt in <module 'threading' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/threading.py'> ignored
```

How do I close the thread so that I can exit my application cleanly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on Aphex's answer, the main thread can't possibly catch the KeyboardInterrupt signal, unless you have very fast fingers. The main thread exits almost immediately! Try this:

```
import threading

def hello_world():
        print 'Hello!'
        threading.Timer(2,hello_world).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        hello_world()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '\nGoodbye!'
    print "main thread exited"
```

More generally, I would not suggest using a self-calling timer like this, just because it creates a lot of threads. Just create one thread and call `time.sleep` inside it.

However, as long as you keep the main thread running, you seem to be able to catch `KeyboardInterrupt` inside. The trick then is to make the thread a `daemon` thread that exits when the main thread exits.

```
import threading
import time

def hello_world():
    while(True):
        print 'Hello!'
        time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hw_thread = threading.Thread(target = hello_world)
    hw_thread.daemon = True
    hw_thread.start()
    try:
        time.sleep(1000)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '\nGoodbye!'
```

This exits automatically after 1000 seconds -- you could make that number even bigger if you like. You could also use a busy-loop to repeat the sleep call, but I don't really see the point.

Answer (score 11):

You just need to set the `Timer` thread as a `daemon`

```
def hello_world(self):
    print 'Hello!'
    t = threading.Timer(2,hello_world)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

That will cause it to exit when the main thread exits, e.g. due to `KeyboardInterrupt`.

The `daemon` setting causes the entire program to exit when the only threads left are `daemon` threads.

Comment: Sweet!  This is the correct answer.    It's the only way to get the Timer threads to prevent Ctrl+C from interfering with exit.    And ultimately... all Timers should get this turned on... because even if you only have one... it's unlikely you want Ctrl+C to kill even one timer.... without shutting down the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-raising the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception: http://effbot.org/zone/stupid-exceptions-keyboardinterrupt.htm

This still may not work though; chances are you're running into this [caveat](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html):

> Threads interact strangely with interrupts: the KeyboardInterrupt exception will be received by an arbitrary thread. (When the signal module is available, interrupts always go to the main thread.)

In short, you can't be sure that the `KeyboardInterrupt` is going to your main thread. To workaround this, you may want to look into the [`signal`](http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html#module-signal) module.

**Edit:** A more elegant way to cancel the thread is to have a shared variable that the thread looks at, and exits if it becomes `false`. Then if you want to kill the thread from your main thread, you set the variable to `false`.

Comment: Re your edit: not a shared variable. Use `threading.Event` for this